# What are cons of websockets?

Tags: http, http-headers, website, web-applications, websocket

I mean why at first place polling and server events exist if websocket can not only solve the problems they are solving but also allow additional functionalities (like bidirectional nature). I guess it has to do something with security and efficiency but on searching I couldn't find any technically subjective explanation to it. The question may sound stupid but I thought to ask rather being confused.

Comment: The question should focus on **one** problem only.

Answer (score 1):

It is just historical evolution. Long-polling was a solution available with a standard `HTTP` protocol and has been widely used since Web 2.0 (2000s). `SSE` was invented specifically for server push and was first implemented in Opera in 2006. `WebSocket` protocol is a more universal solution first implemented in Chrome in 2009.